# Помогите составить сложный sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица, одним запросом хочу получить, к примеру, 2 значения - сумма значений value и сумма значений points, но не могу понять, как составить условия для 2х значений одновременно, возможно ли это? Вот например сумма values:

```
`SELECT SUM(value) AS balance FROM db WHERE id>30 AND value>1000`;
```

Тоже самое для points

```
`SELECT SUM(value) AS balance FROM db WHERE xxx=2 OR yyy=3`;
```

А можно ли как то объединить эти 2 запроса в один?
    `SELECT SUM(value) AS balance, SUM(point) AS points FROM.... WHERE ??`

Всё это при условии, что данные перекликаются и не получится просто соединить эти 2 условия в WHERE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Запихните условия `where` в агрегирующую функцию `sum`:

```
select id,
    sum(if(xxx = 2 or yyy = 3, value, 0)) as balance_1,
    sum(if(id > 30 AND value > 1000, value, 0)) as balance_2
from db
group by id
```

Comment: Отлично, сработало, но считает для всей таблицы в целом, а как посчитать для каждой строки, допустим по id, т.е. вывести всё что выше для каждого id = 1, 2,..N. Поля таблицы я в пример случайные привел

Comment: @Александр обновил ответ. Почитайте, в данном случае, про `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, есть решение поизящнее, но в лоб можно воспользоваться [подзапросами](https://www.site-do.ru/db/sql5.php) -

```
SELECT 
     balance = (SELECT SUM(value) FROM db WHERE id>30 AND value>1000), 
     points = (SELECT SUM(value) FROM db WHERE xxx=2 OR yyy=3`);
```